# Jquery Validate Method letters,numbers and special character

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am using jquery validate to validate my password field.
What i want:

1) Password must contain at least ONE UPPERCASE LETTER

2) Password must contain at least ONE lowercase letter

3) Password must contain at least ONE digit

4) and ALLOW SPECIAL CHARACTERS( !@#$%&* ) only

This is what i have tried but it is validating even if i put ONE UPPERCASE and ONE number:

```
$.validator.addMethod("letters_numbers_special", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || /^(?:[a-zA-Z]|[a-zA-Z])[a-z0-9#$@!]+$/i.test(value);
  //(?=.*[a-zA-Z\d].*)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%&*]
}, "");
```

Comment: If you want to only allow but not require special chars, use `/^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)[a-zA-Z\d!@#$%&*]+$/.test(value)`. Or do you want to have at least one special char from your list and allow virtuallly any char but line break chars?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my original thought was also to use negated character sets rather than matching anything, but it seems to match [too much](https://regex101.com/r/i0M8Z5/2).

Comment: @UnbearableLightness You do not test my pattern correctly at regex101, [this is a correct regex fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/i0M8Z5/3). No one uses multiline strings as passwords in real life. And here is a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wiktor_stribizew/fbzj7s1d/1/).

Comment: Ah, apologies! SO formatted the comment differently and removed the `\n`. I see, that was what was missing from my original idea. Good point.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness SO did not remove anything. Just regex101 is not a place where you *prove* that something works, it is a place where you only *showcase* how a pattern works.

Comment: Yeah I get you now, lesson learnt :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the two patterns below, the lookaheads ensure that in the string there are at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter and one digit.

1. You can use the following pattern if special characters are not required, but allowed.

`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]+$`

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/i0M8Z5/6)

**Matches**:

```
Gpa1
abc01A
```

**Does not match**:

```
donotmatchME!
apple2000@
```

---

2. You can use the following pattern if you also require at least one special character:

`^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%&*])[a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%&*]+$`

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/i0M8Z5/1)

**Matches**:

```
Matchme2018!
regexIScool1!
```

**Does not match**:

```
donotmatchME!
apple2000@
Gpa1
abc01A
```